# Length mismatch with model from Machine Learning MDA package

Tags: r, machine-learning

Can someone help me even phrase what I am trying to do? (I am new to this.)

I am trying out Machine Learning in R now that I have it nailed in Matlab. R is just a passion of mine at the moment.

Data:

```
> head(newzap1209, n=5)
  buoy_douglas  avgtopsum avgstdwin1 stddiff2
1            3 -12.097720   410.4747 410.6323
2            2 -10.462240   260.7213 263.2085
3            2 -11.539432   357.1802 362.3258
4            2  -9.524074   234.8285 234.8571
5            3 -11.498597   356.4736 359.4485
```

Code:

```
library(mda)
fit<-mda(buoy_douglas~.,data=newzap1209)
summary(fit)
predictions<-predict(fit,newzap1209[,2:4])
table(predictions,newzap1209$buoy_douglas)
```

Error message:

> Error in table(predictions, newzap1209$buoy_douglas) : all arguments must have the same length

Everything works except the table!

Same goes for the confusion matrix.

Comment: where did you get the newzap1209 data? post it somewhere so that we can check!

Comment: It's a subset of an original file of 200> variables and it is an aggregate of big data. Not sure what you mean by check. I posted the first5 lines of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that `predictions` and `newzap1209` have mismatching lengths (nrows). Which should be impossible since you generated `fit` from `newzap1209[,2:4]`.

Check the length of each and debug why they mismatch.

Comment: Thanks, length of zap dataset is 4 (number of columns) and predictions have the number of rows in zap (~3000). Maybe its the way I made a subset of my original CSV

Comment: hmmmm tried subsetting the dataset differently still length 4.

Comment: No, we're talking about length in terms of rows. Check is `nrow(zap) == length(predictions)` == 3000 ? (The no.of columns in zap, or used in the model, is irrelevant).

Comment: FYI, we would say 'width' if we were referring to to `ncol(zap)`. Never 'length'.